# Use a puppet module multiple times

Tags: puppet

I'm using a puppet module from Puppet Forge - https://forge.puppet.com/creativeview/mssql_system_dsn

The documentation indicates to use it like this:

```
class {'mssql_system_dsn':
    dsn_name     => 'vcenter',
    db_name      => 'vcdb',
    db_server_ip => '192.168.35.20',
    sql_version  => '2012',
    dsn_64bit    => true,
}
```

I need to create multiple odbc data sources.

However, if I simply duplicate this snippet twice and change the parameters I get a multiple declaration error.

How can I declare this module multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I declare this module multiple times?

You cannot do so without modifying the module.  Although it is possible to declare the same class multiple times if you use include-like syntax, that does not afford a means to use different parameters with different declarations.  This is all connected to the fact that Puppet classes are *singletons*.  I can confirm based on a quick review of [the module's code](https://github.com/creativeview/mssql_system_dsn) that its design does not support defining multiple data sources.

I'd encourage you to file an enhancement request with the module author.  If that does not quickly bear fruit, then you have the option of modifying the module yourself.  It looks like that would be feasible, but not as simple as just changing a `class` keyword to `define`.

Comment: This is essentially correct pending an update of the question under the assumption that this is all on the same node.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, Inasmuch as the OP describes trying unsuccessfully to achieve his objective by copying the given declaration and modifying its parameters, it is reasonable to conclude that he wants to declare multiple data sources on the same node.

Comment: Yes. You are correct that when I said I wanted to create multiple data sources it was on the same machine.

Does anyone have an opinion on what would be the best way to modify the module to support this ability?  

Isn't this a bit of an odd design for this type of resource? - I cannot think of a good reason why the author designed the module in a way that restricts data sources to one per node.

Comment: @djnz, yes, it is an odd design.  The module author seems not to have considered the possibility that anyone would want to manage more than one datasource per machine.  The class should instead be a defined type, or perhaps it should rely on a defined type that can also be used directly.  I'm not prepared to give specific instructions for modifications, and indeed, I recommend making an enhancement request to the module author before considering forking the module.

Comment: @djnz Sounds great. I can go ahead and delete my botched overly optimistic workaround then.

Comment: As the author didn't answer my request and had not merged a pull request from another contributor I created my own module;

https://forge.puppet.com/garfieldmoore/odbc_data_source

If anyone is interested enough to review my module's code and offer improvements or let me know when I have not followed best practises I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As the author didn't answer my request and had not merged a pull request from another contributor I created my own module;

https://forge.puppet.com/garfieldmoore/odbc_data_source

If anyone is interested enough to review my module's code and offer improvements or let me know when I have not followed best practises I would appreciate it